# Outlook.MailItem save as pdf can't be open

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, office-addins

I tried to save my email as pdf to a specific folder when I click send button from outlook. My code looks as below. I can see the file is saved successfully, but it can't be open. Anything wrong in my code? The office version is 2016.

```
private void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
        mailItem.BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatPlain;
        string title = mailItem.Subject;
        mailItem.SaveAs("c://" + title + ".pdf", OlBodyFormat.olFormatRichText);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: PDF != Rich text - give the file a `.doc` extension and it will open. I expect you would need a PDF converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/mailitem-saveas-method-outlook) method of the MailItem class accepts two parameters, the second is 
the file type to save can be one of the following OlSaveAsType constants: olHTML , olMSG , olRTF , olTemplate , olDoc , olTXT , olVCal , olVCard , olICal , or olMSGUnicode. As you can see there is no option for saving the message using the .pdf file format.

However, you may consider using the Word object model for getting the job done.

```
        TheDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(
        docName.Replace(".docx", ".pdf"),
        Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF, 
        OptimizeFor: Word.WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen, 
        BitmapMissingFonts: true, DocStructureTags: false);
```

The [ExportAsFixedFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/document-exportasfixedformat-method-word) method of the Document class allows to save a document as PDF or XPS format. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information about the `WordEditor` property of the Inspector class.

As a last resort you may consider using any third-party .Net components for creating PDF documents from a text or HTML/RTF markup.